# $y = \ln x$ with their $x$ coordinates as $1,2$ and $t$ respectively

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let A,B,P be the points on the curve $y = \ln x$ with their $x$ coordinates as $1,2$ and $t$ respectively.
Find  $$\lim_{t\to\infty} (\cos \angle{BAP})$$

My try :

[image]

I am unable to apply limit.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere? Some problems you are facing? Also, even though the problem is clearly related to graphs (as in: graph of a function), I don't think it's related to graph theory.

Comment: @MattiP. I have edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to find the tangent of the angle: the slope of the line $AB$ is
$$
\frac{\ln2-\ln1}{2-1}=\ln2
$$
and the slope of the line $AP$ is
$$
\frac{\ln t-\ln 1}{t-1}=\frac{\ln t}{t-1}
$$
If $f(t)$ denotes the measure of the angle $BAP$, then
$$
\tan f(t)=\frac{\ln2-\dfrac{\ln t}{t-1}}{1+\ln2 \dfrac{\ln t}{t-1}}
$$
which is essentially what you did. Therefore
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\tan f(t)=\ln 2
$$

Now recall that, for an acute angle $\alpha$,
$$
\cos\alpha=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\alpha}}
$$
and apply theorems on limits.